# Role based authentication and privilages in Slim 3

Tags: php, authentication, rendering, slim, middleware

I implemented a middleware to determine the role and the validity of user token sent in request header.

```
<?php
namespace App\Middleware;


class AuthenticationMiddleware extends Middleware {


//Invoke magic method for all middlewares in Slim
//Next is the next middle
public function __invoke($request, $response, $next) {

    $role = $this->container->authentication->isAuthenticatedForAdminSite($request);
     //$role  = 'Admin';
     if(!isset($role)) { 
        return $response->withRedirect('login'); 
     }
    $this->container->authentication->adminRole = $role;
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    return $response;
}
}
```

The following function returns the name of the role (Admin, Moderator, Customer etc.)

```
$this->container->authentication->isAuthenticatedForAdminSite($request)
```

If it returns nothing user is redirected to login page if not i need to save the value of to role to ivar adminRole in authentication. The reason is that when i render my page i need to determine the type of role to decide what kind of navigation bar the page should show.

The problem arises in the controller for the routing function.

```
public function getOrders($request, $response) {
    $role = $this->container->authentication->adminRole;

    return $this->container->view->render($response, 'orders.html', ['orders' => getOrdersForAdmin("%", $this->container->db), 'role' => $role]);
}
```

$role is always NULL when i test the app on my shared host but it works fine when i test the app on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice to give services (which you fetch from the container) any state. Although I am a little surprised it's not working without an error, it would be more common to assign the role you're getting to the request:

```
// AuthenticationMiddleware
$response = $next($request->withAttribute('role', $role), $response);
```

Then, later on in your controller with the request which is available from the container:

```
$request->getAttribute('role');
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice.I refactored my code and it's definetely a better design pattern, specially when you use middleware.